# Tensorflow: ignore a specific dependency during tf.gradients()

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Given variables y and z, both of which depend on a tensor x. By product rule, if I do tf.gradients(y*z,x), it would give me y'(x)z(x) + z'(x)y(x). Is there a way I can specify y as a constant with respect to x such that tf.gradients(y*z,x) only gives me z'(x)y(x)?

I know  y_=tf.constant(sess.run(y)) will give me y as a constant, but I cannot use that solution in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [tf.stop_gradient()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) to block backpropagation. To block gradients in your example:

```py
y = function1(x)
z = function2(x)

blocked_y = tf.stop_gradient(y)

product = blocked_y * z
```

After you backpropagate through `product`, the backpropagation will continue to `z` and not `y`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could stop gradients with `y = function1(tf.stop_gradient(x), other_variables)` if you need to backpropagate through `y` to trainable variables other than `x`.